# Deploying Geoserver War 2.23.2 on jboss EAP 7.4

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, java-11, geoserver

Hi guys im trying to deploy a geoserver war 2.23.2 on my jboos 7.4 with java 11

i currently deploy with success geoserver war 2.19.2 using jboss 7.4 with java 11

i getting this error when i try to deply geoserver war 2.23.2

```
{"WFLYCTL0080: Servicios fallidos" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"geoserver.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext"}}

17:48:51,425 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 90) No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
17:48:51,565 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 90) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."geoserver.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."geoserver.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY
    at deployment.geoserver.war//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationSource.<clinit>(ConfigurationSource.java:58)
    at deployment.geoserver.war//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.NullConfiguration.<init>(NullConfiguration.java:32)
    at deployment.geoserver.war//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<clinit>(LoggerContext.java:74)
    at deployment.geoserver.war//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:254)
    at deployment.geoserver.war//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:218)
    at deployment.geoserver.war//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:140)
    at deployment.geoserver.war//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:123)
    at deployment.geoserver.war//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:230)
    at deployment.geoserver.war//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.api@2.14.0.redhat-00002//org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:174)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.api@2.14.0.redhat-00002//org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:664)
    at deployment.geoserver.war//org.geotools.util.logging.Log4J2LoggerFactory.getImplementation(Log4J2LoggerFactory.java:74)
    at deployment.geoserver.war//org.geotools.util.logging.Log4J2LoggerFactory.getImplementation(Log4J2LoggerFactory.java:43)
    at deployment.geoserver.war//org.geotools.util.logging.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:72)
    at deployment.geoserver.war//org.geotools.util.logging.Logging.getLogger(Logging.java:221)
    at deployment.geoserver.war//org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener.contextInitialized(GeoserverInitStartupListener.java:89)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:219)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:255)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    ... 8 more

17:48:51,567 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Falló la operación ("deploy") - dirección: ([("deployment" => "geoserver.war")]) - descripción de la falla: {"WFLYCTL0080: Servicios fallidos" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"geoserver.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY"}}`
```

some is using jboss and get this kind of error?

Answer (score 1):

Do you include log4j 2 in your deployment? If so you'll need to exclude the org.apache.logging.log4j.api module from your deployment. Or remove log4j 2 from your deployment.

Comment: the log4j is already load, i try to exclude, and remove to, but i still get the same error

Comment: exclude means using a jboss-deployment-structure.xml or maybe the simplest way is to remove the log4j 2 from your war

Comment: It's likely because you're adding log4j-core to your deployment and not excluding the `org.apache.logging.log4j.api` module from your deployment.